# AngularJS ui-router wrong route undefined parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

So I have these routes:

```
        state('app.editProject', {
            url: '/projects/:projectId/edit',
            templateUrl: 'app/modules/projects/views/edit-project.client.view.html'
        }).
        state('app.viewExpense', {
            url: '/expenses/:expenseId',
            templateUrl: 'app/modules/projects/views/view-expense.client.view.html'
        }).
        state('app.viewIncome', {
            url: '/incomes/:incomeId',
            templateUrl: 'app/modules/projects/views/view-income.client.view.html'
        }).
        state('app.editProjectTab', {
            url: '/projects/:projectId/edit/:currentTab',
            templateUrl: 'app/modules/projects/views/edit-project.client.view.html',
            reloadOnSearch: false
        }).
```

I'm on

```
/app/projects/22/edit/expenses
```

I have a link like this

```
<a data-ng-href="#!/app/expenses/{{ expense.id }}">{{ expense.description }}</a>
```

When I click this link this sends me to the right link but instantly after that sends me to /app/projects/undefined/edit/documents (documents is the last tab)

I found a "workaround" when I see that :projectId is undefined I go back in history.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you sure you don't have any js for clicking on the links that may be redirecting you? can you post the js for the controller or assets that is on that page?

Comment: You can try replacing `data-ng-href` to `ui-sref="app.viewExpense({ expenseId: expense.id })"`

Comment: can you put more of your code up and/or a representative Plunker?

Comment: ui-sref does the same.

Comment: @Mike I can't put it on Plunker because there are a lot of files.

Comment: Fair enough -- but it looks like something in the rest of your route definitions, controller(s), partials, etc. is causing the problem...

Comment: I nailed it down to $scope.changeTab = function(tabTitle) {
            // $stateParams.currentTab = tabTitle;
            if ($stateParams.projectId == null) return;
            $location.path('app/projects/' + $stateParams.projectId + '/edit/' + tabTitle);
            $scope.$emit('$locationChangeSuccess');
        } which was executed after

Comment: Is this problem still not solved?